# HTTPoison request failes on specific machine but works in another machine

Tags: http, elixir, phoenix-framework, httpoison

Am doing a post with HTTPoison, on one machine everything works well, but in the other the same code, with similar environment parameters.

```
HTTPoison.post!("https://remote_api", "", [{"X-TOKEN", System.get_env("API_TOKEN"}, {"Content-Type", "application/json"}])
```

fails with

```
** (HTTPoison.Error) {:options, {:sslv3, {:versions, [:"tlsv1.2", :"tlsv1.1", :tlsv1, :sslv3]}}}
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison.ex:128: HTTPoison.request!/5
```

both machines are setup the same running centos7, but i get expected results in one but not in the other. am not sure what i got wrong

Downgrading to OTP 22 fixed it, thanks Aleksei Matiushkin.

Comment: `:sslv3` is likely the issue. Please check both machines OTP versions and post results here (e. g. by running `erl`.)

Comment: ```

Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V11.0  (abort with ^G)

```

both return the same result

Comment: Support for `SSL 3.0` was completely removed from `Erlang 23.0`. https://www.erlang.org/news/140 What Elixir versions are there? Only `1.10.3` fully supports `OTP23`. Test with `iex`.

Comment: Yikes, now thats some useful info, using elixir `1.9.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bumping `hackney` to version `1.16` worked for me.

```
 defp deps do
    [
      ...
      {:httpoison, "~> 1.6"},
      {:hackney, "~> 1.16"}
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and it looks like [this fix](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/pull/619) in hackney will resolve the problem. It's been merged to `master` but hasn't been released yet.

In the meantime, downgrading to OTP 22 is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for the moment:

```
{:hackney, git: "https://github.com/benoitc/hackney.git", branch: "master", override: true}
```